# pygame keydown combinations (ctrl + key or shift + key)

Tags: python, pygame, combinations, keydown

I have some python code with keydown events happening, I am basically wondering if it is possible to have two keys pressed at a time, like ctrl+a or something like that. Is this possible, or will I have to find a workaround?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [pygame.key.get_mods()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_mods) to get state of special keys like <kbd>Control</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

`get_mods()` gives one integer and you have to use bitwise operators to compare it with constants like `KMOD_SHIFT`

See documentation: [pygame.key](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)

---

**EDIT:** example

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
                print "pressed: SHIFT + A"

pygame.quit()
```

BTW: you can use `KMOD_LSHIFT` or `KMOD_RSHIFT` to test only <kbd>left shift</kbd> or only <kbd>right shift</kbd>.

---

**EDIT:**

BTW: example how to use `get_pressed()`

- you have to use `K_LSHIFT` and `K_LSHIFT` to check both shifts.
- it print "pressed: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>" again and again if you keep <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> pressed.

.

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))

running = True

while running:

    #
    # events
    #

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    #
    # others
    #

    all_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    #print 'shift:', all_keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT], all_keys[pygame.K_RSHIFT]

    if all_keys[pygame.K_a] and (all_keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT] or all_keys[pygame.K_RSHIFT]):
        print "pressed: SHIFT + A"

pygame.quit()
```

---

**BTW:** `get_pressed()` and `get_mods()` give actual information only if `pygame.event.get()` was use before.

---

**EDIT:**

How to recognize <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, , <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:

                mods = pygame.key.get_mods()

                if mods & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and mods & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT and mods & pygame.KMOD_ALT:
                    print "pressed: CTRL+SHIFT+ALT + A"
                elif mods & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and mods & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
                    print "pressed: CTRL+SHIFT + A"
                elif mods & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and mods & pygame.KMOD_ALT:
                    print "pressed: CTRL+ALT + A"
                elif mods & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT and mods & pygame.KMOD_ALT:
                    print "pressed: SHIFT+ALT + A"
                elif mods & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
                    print "pressed: SHIFT + A"
                elif mods & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:
                    print "pressed: CTRL + A"
                elif mods & pygame.KMOD_ALT:
                    print "pressed: ALT + A"
                else:
                    print "pressed: A"


pygame.quit()
```

---

BTW: On my computer is problem with <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> because it is used for native chars. It doesn't work with `KMOD_ALT` and `KMOD_RALT`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, can you see what is wrong here in my code? It should play the sharp version of the note, but still plays as if only 'a' is pressed.


`current_played_sine = { 'a#': MakeSineWave(277.18)}

elif event.key == pygame.K_a and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
    print current_type, 277.18
    current_played_sine['a#'].play(-1)`

Comment: Probably you have `elif event.key == pygame.K_a :` before `elif event.key == pygame.K_a and pygame.key.get_mods()` - first is true also for `SHIFT+A`. You have change order or make `if pygame.key.get_mods() ...:` inside `elif event.key == pygame.K_a :` I made example soon.

Comment: See example in answer.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed, nice and clean code too, thank you

Comment: Problems with alt aren't an issue, I only plan to use SHIFT (and possibly ctrl later on)

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a GUI.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent):
         Frame.__init__(self,parent)
         self.grid()
         self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
         widg = Text(self)
         widg.grid(row=0,column=0)

         self.bind_all("<Control-a>", self.check) #This checks if lower case a is pressed
         self.bind_all("<Control-A>", self.check) #This checks if upper case a is pressed

   def check(self, event): #Make sure to have event inside the function
         print("Control-a pressed")

root = Tk()

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I should have mentioned it was for pygame, if that makes a difference...

Comment: @ZenLogic if its for pygame I have no idea sorry.

Answer (score 1):

For Pygame you should be looking for [get_pressed](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) instead of keydown, cuz keydown happens only once, key down happens until key is released.

for two keys pressed just do a if-stament.

```
# store the result of the get_pressed() in those variables.
if key_ctrl_is_down and key_a_is_down:     
    dowhatever()
```